# Codility Tape Equilibrium Getting zero on some cases

Tags: java, algorithm

### I just took this sample test, and it's right for the most part, but I am not sure why I would get the two cases wrong.

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
>   Array A represents numbers on a tape.
>
> Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two
>   non-empty parts: A[0], A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Auj.png), ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ...,
>   A[N − 1].
>
> The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Auj.png) +
>   ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
>
> In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the
>   first part and the sum of the second part.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 3   A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Auj.png) = 1   A[2] = 2   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 3 We can split
>   this tape in four places:
>
> P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7  P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5  P =
>   3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1  P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7  Write a
>   function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns
>   the minimal difference that can be achieved.
>
> For example, given:
>
> A[0] = 3   A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Auj.png) = 1   A[2] = 2   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 3 the function
>   should return 1, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [2..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000]. Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments).

---

```
class Solution {
 public int solution(int[] A) {
  int sum = 0;
  int subtracted = 0;
  int minDiff = 100000;

  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
   sum += A[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
   sum -= A[i];
   subtracted += A[i];

   int diff = (Math.abs(sum - subtracted));
   if (minDiff > diff) {
    minDiff = diff;
   }

  }

  return minDiff;
 }
}
```

**Coldility Result**

[image: Coldility Result]

Comment: 2nd loop should be `i <  A.length - 1`, you don't want one side of the tape containing nothing. So your code fails for [-1000, 1000], you will return 0 but should return 2000.

Comment: Can't you expand the failing tests to see what they were?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in java and achieved 100% on codility

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
        int sum=0,leftsum=0,rightsum=0,newmin=0,min=0;
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            sum=sum+A[i];
        }
        for(int i=1;i<A.length;i++){
            leftsum=leftsum+A[i-1];
            rightsum=sum-leftsum;
            //System.out.println(leftsum-rightsum);
            if(i==1)
                min=newmin=Math.abs(leftsum-rightsum);
            else
                newmin=Math.abs(leftsum-rightsum);
            min=Math.min(min,newmin);
        }
        return min;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach using just one for loop: The main idea is to accumulate from left and right at the same time until they cross the middle of the array. At that point, they will start sharing elements in the sum, so you need then to evaluate 2 cases:
1st- subtracting the shared elements from the left side
2nd- subtracting the shared elements from the right side

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    int l=A.Length;
    int mid= l%2>0 ? (l/2) : (l/2)-1;

    long ls=0;
    long rs=0;
    long res=long.MaxValue;
    long shared=0;

    for(int i=0, j=l-1; i<l; i++, j--){
        ls=ls+A[i];
        rs=rs+A[j];

        if(i>=mid && i<l-1){

            if(i==j) shared=A[i];
            else if(i>j) shared=shared+A[i]+A[j];

            rs=rs-shared;
            res= res < Math.Abs(ls-rs) ? res : Math.Abs(ls-rs);

            rs=rs+shared;
            ls=ls-shared;
            res= res < Math.Abs(ls-rs) ? res : Math.Abs(ls-rs);

            ls=ls+shared;
        }
    }

    return (int)res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Don't use `int sum = Arrays.stream(A).sum();`, it fails the performance tests. I got all test case right except one with `int sum = Arrays.stream(A).sum();` but it timed out on the largest test case. So I changed it to a for loop sum and it passed with 100%.

```
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int total = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            sum += A[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
            total += A[i];
            int toEndSum = sum - total;
            int diff = Math.abs(total - toEndSum);
            if (diff < result)
                result = diff;

        }
        return result != Integer.MAX_VALUE ? result : 0;
    }
```